# $\mathbb{Q}$ is a flat $\mathbb{Z}$-module

Tags: modules, exact-sequence, flatness

I am working on the following problem:

Show that $0\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}\otimes A\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}\otimes B$ is exact where the map is $1\otimes i$ with $i$ being the inclusion map $A\subset B$.  Conclude that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a flat $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

I have no problem showing that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a flat $\mathbb{Z}$-module by definition, namely that for any monomorphism $0\rightarrow A\rightarrow B$, we get a monomorphism $0\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}\otimes A\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}\otimes B$.

My problem lies in the way the question is presented.  Why does it suffice to use the inclusion map instead of an arbitrary injective map?

My idea on this is that the short exact sequences $0\rightarrow A\xrightarrow{f} B\xrightarrow{g} C\rightarrow 0$ and $0\rightarrow \text{Im}(f)\xrightarrow{i} B\xrightarrow{g} C\rightarrow 0$ are isomorphic via the obvious maps where $i$ is the inclusion map.  Is this why it suffices to only consider the inclusion map in the problem above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because $A\simeq\operatorname{Im}f$ and tensoring an isomorphism always gives an isomorphism. Hence it is equivalent to prove that tensoring the inclusion morphism or tensoring the original injective morphism results in an injective morphism.

Btw, any rings of fractions is a flat $A$-module.